# How to select last three rows in different (non-adjacent) columns in EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

```
Sheets("AVG-BW").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2, -4).Resize(3, 3).Copy Sheets("Data").Range("A28")
```

I need to select last 3 values automatically from column E, D and A. 
I used the code given above but it selecting C,B and A. HELP ME.

Comment: for this case u need to store ranges in array

Comment: The reason it selects those cells is:  `Sheets("AVG-BW").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` this selects the last cell in column `E`.  `.Offset(-2, -4)` tells it to go up by two cells, and left by four cells - so you must at a minimum have data in E3 otherwise it will try and reference off the sheet (-4 is why it selects column A).  `.Resize(3, 3)` tells it to resize the single size to a 3x3 grid of selected cells (so with data in E3 it will select A1:C3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Dim sws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set sws = Sheets("AVG-BW")
Set dws = Sheets("Data")

lr = sws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Union(sws.Range("E" & lr).Offset(-2, -4).Resize(3), sws.Range("E" & lr).Offset(-2, -1).Resize(3), sws.Range("E" & lr).Offset(-2).Resize(3))
rng.Copy dws.Range("A28")
```

Comment: *(+1)* Great solution! Maybe (just for good measure) add a line like `If lr < 3 Then MsgBox "Not enough rows. Aborting...": Exit Sub`.

Comment: @Ralph Thanks for the feedback and +1. :) Yes, that line can be included to check the absence of data.